# Unable to add System.Net.ServicePointManager in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

We need to integrate our UWP app with a partner application that requires System.Net.Servicepointmanager class to work. We are using .Net framework 4.7.03056 and UWP version 16299 in visual studio 2017 (15.6.6) and this class is neither part of the core nor can we get it from somewhere. Is there something we are missing?

Answer (score 1):

Target: 17134

Min: 16299

It's working (-:

If I were you, I'd set both Target & Min to 16299 too. It might work too, but as I've no 16299 SDK installed, I can't test it.